# Ironsource Banner Only Showing In main Activity and in other activities after implementation not showing

Tags: java, android, ads, banner, ironsource

I have Implemented *Ironsouce* banner in all activity with below method but its only work in main activity and in other activities show error message

API: Multiple calls to *init* without ad units are not allowed
 API: L a - can't load banner - *loadBanner* already called and still in progress
 API: L a - can't load banner - *loadBanner* already called and still in progress

```
    IronSource.init(this, "APP_ID");
    IronSource.setMetaData("Facebook_IS_CacheFlag","IMAGE");
    final FrameLayout bannerContainer = findViewById(R.id.adview);
    IronSourceBannerLayout bannerLayout = IronSource.createBanner(this, ISBannerSize.SMART);
    IronSource.loadBanner(bannerLayout, (String) "DefaultBanner");
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    bannerContainer.addView(bannerLayout);
    IronSource.loadBanner(bannerLayout);

    IronSource.loadInterstitial();

    IronSource.setInterstitialListener(new InterstitialListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInterstitialAdReady() {
            IronSource.showInterstitial("DefaultInterstitial");
        }

        @Override
        public void onInterstitialAdLoadFailed(IronSourceError ironSourceError) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onInterstitialAdOpened() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onInterstitialAdClosed() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onInterstitialAdShowSucceeded() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onInterstitialAdShowFailed(IronSourceError ironSourceError) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onInterstitialAdClicked() {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving back and forth form one activity to another than you have to destroy the banner, always destroy banner before loading a new banner,

so while going form activity A to B  destroy banner in A than go to B and load the  in B.

```
  IronSource.destroyBanner(banner);
```

and while coming back form B to A than also destroy in B and again reload the banner in A

you can use onBackPressed to destroy the banner

```
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        IronSource.destroyBanner(banner);
        finish();
    }
```

If there is a backbutton on nav bar

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            IronSource.destroyBanner(banner);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

this may vary in your case `android.R.id.home`

Answer (score 0):

When starting a new activity call IronSource.destroyBanner(banner);

- In mainActivity override OnResume and add if(banner.isDestroyed()) Like this:

```html
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IronSource.onResume(this);
        if(banner.isDestroyed())
            SecondBannerInit();
    }
```

- SecondBannerInit:

```html
 private void SecondBannerInit(){

        banner = IronSource.createBanner(MainActivity.this, ISBannerSize.BANNER);
        bannerContainer.addView(banner, 0);

        IronSource.loadBanner(banner);
        banner.setLevelPlayBannerListener(new LevelPlayBannerListener() {
            // Invoked each time a banner was loaded. Either on refresh, or manual load.
            //  AdInfo parameter includes information about the loaded ad
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(AdInfo adInfo) {Log.d(TAG, "Banner Ad Loaded");}
            // Invoked when the banner loading process has failed.
            //  This callback will be sent both for manual load and refreshed banner failures.
            @Override
            public void onAdLoadFailed(IronSourceError error) {Log.d(TAG, "Banner Ad Failed " + error.toString());}
            // Invoked when end user clicks on the banner ad
            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(AdInfo adInfo) {}
            // Notifies the presentation of a full screen content following user click
            @Override
            public void onAdScreenPresented(AdInfo adInfo) {}
            // Notifies the presented screen has been dismissed
            @Override
            public void onAdScreenDismissed(AdInfo adInfo) {}
            //Invoked when the user left the app
            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication(AdInfo adInfo) {}

        });
    }
```

don't forget to override OnBackPressed() Method in the SecondActivity and Destroy the banner.

Happy Coding.